# Legend on top of Diagram left aligned with x axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, legend, boxplot

I have a set of Boxplot diagrams generated using Python3 (tikzplotlib). I would like to add legends now that are left aligned with the x-Axis and positioned on top of the diagrams.

Currently I solve the problem using the following code:

```
\begin{axis}[
...
legend cell align={left},
legend style={fill opacity=0.8, draw opacity=1, text opacity=1, at={(0.31,1.28)}, anchor=north, draw=white!80!black, fill=white!89.8039215686275!black},
legend entries={$4$-important item,
                $5$-important item,
                $6$-important item},
...
]

\addlegendimage{only marks, red}
\addlegendimage{only marks, green!50.1960784313725!black}
\addlegendimage{only marks, blue}
...
```

Problem is that the position is never exactly the same especially when the number of parameters in the legend varies. (The position is currently defined by the subparameter in `legend style`, `at={(...)}`.) Is there a better and more precise way to achieve the same result?

Thank you very much in advance for your proposals!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/108724)

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks for welcoming me - is the link you provided to me some hint that I did something wrong?

Comment: No, Sorry, That is just  a helpful link.

Comment: Try: `legend style={at={(0.0,1.0)}, anchor=south west},`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: @nidhin can you rewrite your comment as answer please - it did exactly what I tried to achieve - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using

```
legend style={at={(0.0,1.0)}, anchor=south west},
```

- `at={(0.0,1.0)}` places the legends on the top left corner.
- `anchor=south west` draws the legend box such that the bottom left corner is placed at the point `(0,1)`.

#### output

[image]

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={at={(0.0,1.0)}, anchor=south west},
legend entries={one,two,three,}
]
\addplot{1};
\addplot{2};
\addplot{3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again!